# What is the advantage of using Factory method pattern here

Tags: javascript, design-patterns

I am learning the `Javascript` tips from this http://code.google.com/p/jslibs/wiki/JavascriptTips site.

I came to see about the `Factory method pattern`. They shown the following example

```
Complex = new function() {

        function Complex(a, b) {
                // ...
        }

        this.fromCartesian = function(real, mag) {

                return new Complex(real, imag);
        }

        this.fromPolar = function(rho, theta) {

                return new Complex(rho * Math.cos(theta), rho * Math.sin(theta));
        }
}


var c = Complex.fromPolar(1, Math.pi); // Same as fromCartesian(-1, 0);
```

But I can't guess why actually this is called as `Factory method pattern`. I want to know about this `Factory method pattern` and advantage of using this and especially to know where to exactly use this.

Comment: @IanAtkin, The link that you provided will not help the OP to know about the `Factory Method Pattern`

Comment: @universal How about http://c2.com/cgi-bin/wiki?FactoryMethodPattern? That tells me everything I need to know about FMP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Factory pattern may be described as a function that creates a class instance (like a real factory produces cars or toys, etc.) In your example, Complex is a factory that can create instances in two ways: cartesian or polar.

The Factory pattern is useful in a number of scenarios, including:

- the Factory maintains information needed (such as a sequence number, or usually something more complex) for creating instances
- the Factory maintains the instances over their lifetimes (such a pool of resources).